# Why did Lavan say "Ashre"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In *parashas* "*Vayetze*", 31:25, we have the following in *Onkelos*:

> וְאַדְבֵּיק לָבָן יָת יַעֲקֹב וְיַעֲקֹב פְּרַס יָת מַשְׁכְּנֵהּ בְּטוּרָא וְלָבָן אַשְׁרֵי יָת אֲחוֹהִי בְּטוּרָא דְּגִלְעָד.‏
>
> *Lavan* reached *Yaakov*. *Yaakov* pitched his tent on the mountain. *Lavan* — "*Ashre*" with his relatives on *Gil'ad* Mountain.

Why did *Lavan* say "*Ashre*" with his relatives?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We find the answer [elsewhere in the parshah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0130.htm#13).

> וַתֹּאמֶר לֵאָה--בְּאָשְׁרִי, כִּי אִשְּׁרוּנִי בָּנוֹת
>
> And Le'ah said "'Ashrei,' because my daughters made me happy."

We therefore see that when one's daughters make one happy, he (or she) should say Ashrei.

Therefore, when Lavan is trying to tell how much he loves his daughters and is upset at Ya'akov having taken them (31:26-28), he first made sure to show that he loved his daughters (in verse 25) by saying Ashrei.

Answer (score 7):

It was a fast day. *Lavan* was part of a group of seven people fasting, so wanted to pray *mincha* and read "*Vay'chal*". Of course, he started with "*Ashre*". (Later, *Yaakov* told him (per *Mishna B'rura* 566:14) that you need ten for "*Vay'chal*".)

---

Let's see why this was so, and how we see it from the *p'sukim*:

#### It was a fast day:

Let's work backwards from the next known date in the *Chumash*. In 33:16–[17](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%96) we see *Yaakov* going to *Sukos*, where the *g'mara* ([*M'gila* 17](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%90)) says he spent the summer season. Thus, he got there the day before *Pesach*. That happened the same day he had met *Esav*.

The previous night, the night of the fourteenth of *Nisan*, thus, *Yaakov* met the "man" (or angel). On the thirteenth, then, he sent presents to *Esav*. This is the start of chapter 32. 32:1 indicates that this is the day after the events of the end of chapter 31. Thus, *Lavan* said "*Ashre*" on the 12th of *Nisan*.

What day of the week was this? Well, [31](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0131):24 says it was the day after he got to *Gil'ad* Mountain, and *Rashi* to 31:23 says that *that* was the day after *Lavan* had found out *Yaakov*'s departure — which, 31:32 says, was בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁלִישִׁי, Tuesday. So it was Thursday, the twelfth of *Nisan*.

Of course, Thursday, the twelfth of *Nisan*, is a fast day, *taanis b'choros*.

#### *Lavan* was part of a group of seven people:

This occurred thirteen years after *Yaakov* married, so none of his sons were *bar mitzva*. However, in the presence of nine adults, one boy can count toward a *minyan* (*Orach Chayim* 55:4). In 31:51, *Lavan* realizes "וְעֵדָה הַמַּצֵּבָה, the monument makes a *minyan*" (as we see in the *g'mara* ([*M'gila* 23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%92_%D7%91)) that "עֵדָה" means "*minyan*"). Thus, the monument, *Yaakov*, and one of his sons made the *minyan*, so *Lavan* had seven people. *Lavan* was pointing out that he had a *minyan* because he realized now that you need one for "*Vay'chal*".

#### *Lavan*'s seven people were all fasting:

This we see from *Rashi* to 31:23, who translates "אֶחָיו", literally "his brothers", as "his relatives". What could have compelled *Rashi* to do so? It must be *Rashi* knew *Lavan*'s "brothers" were not really his brothers, because they were all *b'choros*.

Comment: Now we can understand why Onkelos translates "תָּקַע" as saying Ashrei, because "מצות עשה מן התורה לזעוק **ולהריע בחצוצרות** על כל צרה שתבא על הצבור" ([Rambam Ta'aniyos 1:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=20&hilite=))!

Answer (score 4):

You are thinking of the wrong Ashrei (Psalms 145). He actually recited Psalms 41 which contains the verse ([:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2641.htm)):

> אשרי משכיל אל דל ביום רעה ימלטהו יקוק:‏
>   Praiseworthy [*Ashrei*] is the [Maskil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maskil) against the poor one; on a troubled day God will save him.

Lavan views himself as pitted against poor Yaakov (because all of Yaakov's property should really belong to Lavan) and therefore prays that God will save him.

Some Achronim uphold your view that this is the regular Ashrei prayer, viewing אשרי יושבי ביתך "praiseworthy are the dwellers of Your house" as trying to counteract Yaakov. Immediately prior to Lavan's saying Ashrei, Yaakov had set up the Mishkan, God's house, in Persia (פרס). Lavan knew that when Achashverosh tried doing this ([Esther 1:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3301.htm#4), [Megillah 12a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=12&format=pdf)) his wife ended up dying. Since Lavan cared about Yaakov's wives (his daughters) he prayed to God to intercede on his daughters behalf and protect them.