# Is Haman actually from Amalek?

Tags: purim, haman

From where do we know that Haman is actually descendant from Amalek?
(I am looking for places besides Gemara Megillah https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a.1?lang=bi)

Please be specific with sources cited.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33842/why-is-haman-called-an-agagite-and-not-an-amalekite

Comment: Megilla 30A אִיתְּמַר: פּוּרִים שֶׁחָל לִהְיוֹת בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת, רַב אָמַר: מַקְדִּימִין פָּרָשַׁת זָכוֹר, וּשְׁמוּאֵל אָמַר: מְאַחֲרִין. רַב אָמַר מַקְדִּימִין — כִּי הֵיכִי דְּלָא תִּיקְדּוֹם עֲשִׂיָּה לִזְכִירָה.

Answer (score 3):

[Megilla 13A](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a.1?lang=bi)

> וּמָה שִׁילֵּם לִי יְמִינִי — דְּלָא קַטְלֵיהּ שָׁאוּל לַאֲגָג, דְּאִתְיְלִיד מִינֵּיהּ הָמָן דִּמְצַעַר לְיִשְׂרָאֵל.

> And how a Benjamite has repaid me is referring to the fact that Saul, who was from the tribe of Benjamin, did not kill the Amalekite king Agag immediately, from whom Haman was later born, and he caused suffering to the Jewish people.

Comment: Thank you, i edited my original question.

Comment: Is there something specific you looking for that the Gemara doesn’t cover?

Comment: I feel that the coverage of this issue isnt really represented in that gemara. for example, why wasn't Haman called the "amaleiki" etc.

Answer (score 2):

See [Masechta Sofrim 13](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.13.6?lang=bi) which shows the direct lineage:

> המן המדתא אגגי בר ביזא בר אפליטוס בר דיוס בר דיזוט בר פרוס בר נידן בר בעלקן בר אנטמירוס בר הורם בר הודורס בר שגר בר נגר בר פרמשתא בר ויזתא בר עמלק בר לחינתיה דאליפז בוכריה דעשו
>
> Haman the son of Hammedasa the Aggagite, son of Buza, son of Aflutos, son of Deosis, son of Paros, son of Nidan, son of Be‘alkon, son of Antamarus, son of Ḥarum, son of Hadoras, son of Shazar, son of Nagar, son of Parmashta, son of Vayezasa, son of Amaleḳ, son of the concubine of Eliphaz the firstborn of Esav

Comment: That's 18 generations listed to Esav. Counting from his brother Yaakov we have Yehuda Peretz Chetzron Rom Aminadav Nachshon Salmah Boaz Oved Yishai David Solomon Rechavam Aviya Asa Yehoshafat Yoram Ahaziah Yoash Amatzia Uzzia Yotam Achaz Hezekia Menashe Amon Yoshiya Tzidkiya is 28 generations. Since Haman is even younger than Tzidkiya (and, at least according to the midrash, at least Yaakov Yehuda Boaz David and Hezekia were well on in years when they begot their respective heirs), this is probably not a complete direct lineage

Comment: Notably nowhere on that list is a person named Agag.